# Удаление конкретной части из строки php

Tags: php

Есть строка -

`"C:/OpenServer/domains/flowers/telegram/Exceptions/Telegram\Bot\Events\EmitsEvents.php"`

Мне нужно из нее вырезать `"/Telegram\Bot"`, чтобы получилось:

```
"C:/OpenServer/domains/flowers/telegram/Exceptions\Events\EmitsEvents.php"
```

Как это сделать?(

UPD: Весь код функции:

```
$path = ROOT . 'telegram/' . $path . $class_name . '.php';
str_replace('/Telegram\Bot', '', $path);
echo $path . '<br>';
```

Проблема в том, что к $class_name содержится Telegram\Bot, из-за этого он не инклюдит нужный файл. Мне нужно вырезать именно эту часть

//Для Razmik Galstyan
Код:

```
    $class_name = 'Telegram\Bot\Events\EmitsEvents';   
    $pattern = '#\/Telegram\\Bot#m';
    echo $class_name . '<br>';
    $class_name = preg_replace($pattern, '', $class_name);
    echo $class_name . '<br>';
```

Comment: удалить `"/Telegram\Bot"` из строки или взять его?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan именно удалить

Comment: `str_replace('/Telegram\\Bot', '');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью `preg_replace`:

Вот пример:

```
<?php

    $pattern = '#(/?Telegram)(\\\Bot)#';
    $string = '"C:/OpenServer/domains/flowers/telegram/Exceptions/Telegram\Bot\Events\EmitsEvents.';

    $string = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);    

    print_r($string);

?>
```

Comment: Не получается :(

Comment: Добавил в конец кода

Comment: Проблема с символом \. Сделал просто $pattern = '/Telegram/'; - работает

Comment: @Alexxosipov уже работает, немного поменял регулярку.